# database table not being created

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am designing a sql db for business listings in my local area. I am using mySQL WorkBench to design the DB, how ever I am having some issues with one of the tables in the DB not being able to be created.

This is what the db design looks like

[image]

The issue I am having is with BusinessHours, I am finding it abit confusing because I want to relate it with a Foregin key to BusinessDirectory (each businessDirectory has many BusinessHours) 'one to many' so that you can represent the 7 days of the week. Hope that makes sense.

This is the sql generated using mySQL workbench

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Members`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Members` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Members` (
  `idMembers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMembers`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (
  `idBusinessDirectory` INT NOT NULL ,
  `businessName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `businessDescription` VARCHAR(1000) NULL ,
  `businessLogo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `idMembers` INT NULL ,
  `directoryCategory` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBusinessDirectory`) ,
  INDEX `idMembers_idx` (`idMembers` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idMembers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMembers` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Members` (`idMembers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`BusinessAddress`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessAddress` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessAddress` (
  `idBusinessDirectory` INT NOT NULL ,
  `addressNumber` VARCHAR(5) NULL ,
  `addressAreaName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `addressLat` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
  `addressLong` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBusinessDirectory`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idBusinessDirectory`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBusinessDirectory` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (`idBusinessDirectory` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`BusinessHours`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessHours` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessHours` (
  `idBusinessDirectory` INT NOT NULL ,
  `dayOfWeek` INT NULL ,
  `openingTime` TIME NULL ,
  `closingTime` TIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBusinessDirectory`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idBusinessDirectory`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBusinessDirectory` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (`idBusinessDirectory` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `mydb` ;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

So I was hoping that someone can help me figure out why I am unable to add BusinessHours table to my db.

Here are two screenshots showing the error msgs I am reciving in phpMyAdmin

[image]

[image]

any help would be appreciated

Final Updated sql;

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Members`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Members` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Members` (
  `idMembers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMembers`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (
  `idBusinessDirectory` INT NOT NULL ,
  `businessName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `businessDescription` VARCHAR(1000) NULL ,
  `businessLogo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `idMembers` INT NULL ,
  `directoryCategory` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBusinessDirectory`) ,
  INDEX `idMembers_idx` (`idMembers` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idMembers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMembers` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Members` (`idMembers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`BusinessAddress`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessAddress` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessAddress` (
  `idBusinessDirectory_BusinessAddress` INT NOT NULL ,
  `addressNumber` VARCHAR(5) NULL ,
  `addressAreaName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `addressLat` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
  `addressLong` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBusinessDirectory_BusinessAddress`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idBusinessDirectory_BusinessAddress`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBusinessDirectory_BusinessAddress` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (`idBusinessDirectory` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`BusinessHours`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessHours` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`BusinessHours` (
  `idBusinessDirectory_BusinessHours` INT NOT NULL ,
  `dayOfWeek` INT NULL ,
  `openingTime` TIME NULL ,
  `closingTime` TIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBusinessDirectory_BusinessHours`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idBusinessDirectory_BusinessHours`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBusinessDirectory_BusinessHours` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (`idBusinessDirectory` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `mydb` ;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

this is what the Foregin key tab should look like

[image]

thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint name `idBusinessDirectory` for foreign key is repeated in table `BusinessHours` and `BusinessAddress` .

Give different name to the constraint.

**UPDATED**

Follow a proper FK naming convention so that such error never pops up and just by the name of constraint we can know the tables involved in the constraint.

```
fk_[referencing table name]_[referenced table name]_[referencing field name]
```

So in your case the constraints will be

EDIT Update your code with this

```
BusinessAddress Table

CONSTRAINT `fk_BusinessAddress_BusinessDirectory_idBusinessDirectory`
FOREIGN KEY (`idBusinessDirectory` )
REFERENCES `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (`idBusinessDirectory` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)


BusinessHours Table

CONSTRAINT `fk_BusinessHours_BusinessDirectory_idBusinessDirectory`
FOREIGN KEY (`idBusinessDirectory` )
REFERENCES `mydb`.`BusinessDirectory` (`idBusinessDirectory` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

All your constraints are stored in this `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` in INNODB

[**REFER**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: idBusinessDirectory is the PK of BusinessDirectory it was supposed to be the FK for both BusinessAddress and BusinessHours, is it the right thing to change if I am wanting it to be my FK?

Comment: MySQL WorkBench should handle this automatically but it doesn't

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh what are you saying it should handle automatically but dosnt?

Comment: I mean that MySQL WorkBench should handle duplicate constraint name automatically but it doesn't, you have to manually check that

Comment: @Meherzad thank you very much for the code example! I understand it now... its made me understand how it works in the mySQL WorkBench interface.. I know exactly what to do now :) thanks

Comment: hrmm.. okay so it didnt work still working on your solution will mark correct once I figue it out :)

Comment: I fixed it, I was still getting the same error even after updating it to get the updated xml. What I then found out in the Foreign Keys tab of mySQL WorkBench you name the foreign key the name of the cell in your table. not the name of the actual foreign key.. thats what was mucking it up. I will add updated sql and a screenshot so you can see. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Welcome... :) Glad to help..  Check the updated code to follow proper FK naming convention.. will help you..